How to stay on Vert.x context instead of Project Reactors?
I am developing a Java Quarkus application. I am trying to use the Mutiny framework for any blocking operation I might have.
Now I am using the async blob service client from Azure to store blobs. This is using Project Reactor under the hood. For some reason, whenever I call this blob client to upload a blob I get the following error message:
[Exception 0] org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: HR000069: Detected use of the reactive Session from a different Thread than the one which was used to open the reactive Session - this suggests an invalid integration; original thread [305]: 'vert.x-eventloop-thread-1' current Thread [282]: 'reactor-http-nio-3'
[Exception 1] java.lang.IllegalStateException: HR000068: This method should exclusively be invoked from a Vert.x EventLoop thread; currently running on thread 'reactor-http-nio-3'
What I'm doing is the following:

Call database using Hibernate Panache Reactive.
Store blobs using async client

For that I have the following code (it's an excerpt):
storeEntity.store(entity)
                .onItem().transformToUni(ignored -> storeBlob.storeMultiple(blobs))
                .onFailure().recoverWithUni(exception -> {
                    Log.error(
                            entity.getId().toString(),
                            "An error occurred while handling new entity.",
                            exception
                    );

                    return Uni.createFrom().failure(exception);
                });

This is calling my BlobHandler for which I have the following code:
public Uni<Void> storeMultiple(List<BlobData> blobs) {
        List<Uni<Void>> uploadUnis = blobs.stream().map(blobData -> Uni
                .createFrom()
                .publisher(AdaptersToFlow.publisher(
                        blobContainerClient.getBlobAsyncClient(
                                blobData.getBlobName()
                        ).upload(
                                BinaryData.fromBytes(blobData.getData())
                        )
                ))
                .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool())
                .onItem().ignore().andContinueWithNull()
        ).toList();

        return Uni
                .join()
                .all(uploadUnis)
                .usingConcurrencyOf(blobConfig.uploadConcurrency())
                .andFailFast()
                .onItem()
                .ignore()
                .andContinueWithNull()
                .onFailure()
                .recoverWithUni(exception -> {
                    Log.error("Upload multiple blobs", "An error occurred while uploading one or more blobs.", exception);

                    return Uni.createFrom().failure(new BlobProblem("An error occurred while uploading one or more blobs.", exception));
                })
                .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool());
    }

I am assigning a list of Unis to a variable, then I am joining them together and executing them, and whenever one of them fails I immediately fail the operation.
I already tried some stuff using .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool()) but that also didn't work.
Does anyone know what I should do?
